# Cocoa: Application closes when window invisible

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm making a Cocoa application with two windows. I want to hide both of these windows, call some screen capture functionality and then restore the windows. I use

```
[mainWindow orderOut:self];
```

to hide the window, but when I do this, the whole application closes. In my AppDelegate I have the function:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication*)sender 
{
    return YES;
}
```

Am I hiding the window incorrectly? Why does the AppDelegate think the window has been closed when using orderOut?

My app works perfectly without using the method above in AppDelegate, I added it in as a final step to terminate the application when I actually close all of the windows. Can anyone suggest how to make my windows temporarily invisible without closing the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove method **applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed**. Application will remain open. This is the normal behavior on OS X. You can close all the windows of Chrome or Safari and they will remain open. OS X will close them if there is a need, like on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I forget... can you setVisible: of a window? If so that would solve it.

The only other thing would be to set a BOOL when you programatically close the windows... iClosed Windows = YES. Then set it to NO when you restore the windows... then check that bool in the delegate method and return YES or NO accordingly.

Comment: I haven't found a way to setVisible for windows. 

I've been trying to set a flag like you've suggested but don't know how to access the BOOL/int from the AppDelegate. Currently looking for an example of this!

Comment: Just make it an instance variable in your .h file. Then in your init or awakeFromNib or applicationDidFinishLaunching methods give it an initial value of NO. Then it's a global variable accessible to any method in your .m file.